# Function checking values of type chars

Tags: c++, arrays, function

I am new to programming and have an exercise in which I create a function to check whether an array of type char hold particular values.
Here is my function:

```
bool arrCheck(char n[],char pos1,char pos2,char pos3,int size)
{
    int n1,n2,n3;
    for (int i=0;i<size;i++)
    {
        if (n[i]==pos1)
        {
            n1=1;
        }
        if (n[i]==pos2)
        {
            n2=1;
        }
        if (n[i]==pos3)
        {
            n3=1;
        }
    }
    if ((n1==1)&&(n2==1)&&(n3==1))
    {
        return true;
    }
}
```

here is my test program:

```
int main()
{
    char a[5]={'6','1','a','a','a'};
    if (arrCheck(a,'1','6','9',5))
    {
        cout<<"true\n";
    }
}
```

I thought the result is supposed to be false but all I got is true. What did I do wrong?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

**THE CODE IS ALRIGHT**. You just forgot to add some statements and this is causing the error (it might or might not have been silly on your part).

Your definition of the function `arrCheck()` is incomplete. It returns `true` if a certain condition is fulfilled but what if it isn't? In that case, you must return `false`. But in your code, **false is never returned**. So firstly, you've gotta add an `else` statement after the last `if` statement in the `arrCheck()` method to this:

```
if((n1==1)&&(n2==1)&&(n3==1)){
    return true;
}
else{
    return false; //this has to be added
}
```

It can now return `false` if such a case is encountered.
Also, you must display "**false**" in the main method if `arrCheck()` returns `false`. You are recommended to add an `else` statement after the `if` statement in the `main()` method. See the modification below:

```
if (arrCheck(a,'1','6','9',5))
{
    cout<<"true\n";
}
else{
    cout<<"false\n"; //it must show false;
}
```

Once you correct these, your code will produce the correct output.

---

**P.S.** This answer serves as an elaboration of the answer earlier submitted by [@KUSHAGRA GUPTA](https://stackoverflow.com/users/6059280/kushagra-gupta).

Answer (score 1):

`n1`, `n2` and `n3` are default-initialized and they have indeterminate values at first. Initialize them before checking their values. Also do not forget to return something even when the condition is false.

Try this:

```
bool arrCheck(char n[],char pos1,char pos2,char pos3,int size)
{
    int n1=0,n2=0,n3=0;
    for (int i=0;i<size;i++)
    {
        if (n[i]==pos1)
        {
            n1=1;
        }
        if (n[i]==pos2)
        {
            n2=1;
        }
        if (n[i]==pos3)
        {
            n3=1;
        }
    }
    return (n1==1)&&(n2==1)&&(n3==1);
}
```

Using `bool`to store boolean values and using `const` to mark that the contents of array won't be changed may be better .

```
bool arrCheck(const char n[],char pos1,char pos2,char pos3,int size)
{
    bool n1=false,n2=false,n3=false;
    for (int i=0;i<size;i++)
    {
        n1=n1||(n[i]==pos1);
        n2=n2||(n[i]==pos2);
        n3=n3||(n[i]==pos3);
    }
    return n1&&n2&&n3;
}
```

Answer (score 1):

1) Use a bool variable instead of three int variable 
2) Initialize it (You have not initialized the int variable and they have random    garbage value)
3) Also add else condition to return false value (Your code is not returning false).
4)Also print false in main function using else condition.
Hope this helps you..!

Answer (score 0):

> ```
> int n1,n2,n3;
> ```

This line leads to **undefined behaviour** because you do not initialise the variables yet attempt to read from them later on even if not all of them have been assigned a value:

> ```
> if ((n1==1)&&(n2==1)&&(n3==1))
> ```

Fix the undefined behaviour by initialising the variables to 0:

```
int n1 = 0;
int n2 = 0;
int n3 = 0;
```

There is another case of undefined behaviour when your function does not state what to return if the condition is not true. Fix this, too:

```
if ((n1==1)&&(n2==1)&&(n3==1))
{
    return true;
}
else
{
    return false;
}
```

Or simply:

```
return (n1==1)&&(n2==1)&&(n3==1);
```

Answer (score 0):

change that line to like this.`int n1= 0,n2= 0,n3 = 0;`
because when uninitialized these variable have garbage values.

```
bool arrCheck(char n[],char pos1,char pos2,char pos3,int size)
{
    int first = 0,second = 0, third = 0; 
    for (int i=0;i<size;i++) {
        if (n[i]==pos1) {
         first = 1;
        } else if (n[i]==pos2) {
          second = 1;
        } else if (n[i]==pos3) {
          third = 1;
        }
   }

   if( first+ second + third == 3) 
       return true;
   else
      return false;
}
```